# Unable to load XAML through XamlReader

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application. Source is [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnT69jNVRGEne-MxRAxif7sOG28). My requirement is, if the use click the Save button, I want to capture the current window's XAML including inputs and save it to the database. After that in application, somewhere else, I need to load back that window from DB. I tried this using [XamlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Its working fine if I didnt name the controls in Xaml. If I add x:Name attribute in Xaml for any control, it gives exception as shown below. Please help.

[image]

Comment: I tried, unable to find solution.

Comment: Did you even read the message ? Seems like you have a duplicate name.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Please check the source. I dont have any duplicate name.

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots; properly formatted text is much more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this and it worked.

```
var win = new Window();
win.Name = this.Name;
win.Content = this.Content;
var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(win);
```

But still I cant do like this if the window have a DataGrid in it, since DataGrid doesnt support serialization. Need to find out some other method.

Answer (score 3):

if you put a `Console.WriteLine(window);` behind `var window = XamlWriter.Save(this);` like so:

```
 var window = XamlWriter.Save(this);
 Console.WriteLine(window);
```

you get this printed:

```
<MainWindow Title="MainWindow" Width="525" Height="350" Visibility="Visible" xmlns="clr-namespace:XamlReaderSample;assembly=XamlReaderSample" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><av:Grid><av:StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
<av:TextBox Width="100" xml:space="preserve" /><av:TextBox Width="100" Margin="0,10,0,0" xml:space="preserve" />
<av:Button Name="btnSave" Width="80" Margin="0,10,0,0">Save</av:Button> 
</av:StackPanel></av:Grid></MainWindow>
```

within this code there is a button named btnSave. in the rest of your code you try to create a new window from that code. once you try to create that window, you have a 2nd button (besides the one you did click) with that name. and that causes the error.